# R+gtsummary: Compare subgroups individually

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a very specific request regarding gtsummary / tbl_summary. I am sorry that I can't provide a code example or attempts to do this because I think it is not a function of gtsummary but I wanted to have asked a least.

I have taken this picture from the official gtsummary page. I am wondering if there is any feature to compare the subgroups to a baseline, let's say compare all to Grade I? I know that you can compare all values to each other using "add_p()" but that it is not what I am after.

Any ideas? If it is not possible with gtsummary, is anyone aware of another package that might solve the problem? Otherwise, I would need to do it by hand.

[image]

Comment: Philipp, you can calculate the comparison you are after as a new column in your dataset and then present it in {gt}. You are right {gt} has some functionality, but cannot account for all - possible - cases. Thus, you can develop your `add_my_comparison()` function/operation to augment the table. Think addin a new column with the desired values (in your case comparison results). This is where you can come in and use {gt} to present the table (of your results) in a publication ready form. Good luck

Comment: The gtsummary package does not calculate p-values natively for subsets of categorical variables. You can add any statistic you'd like using the `gtsummary::add_stat()` function.